# What Can Be Done To Make The Human GastroIntestinal System More Omnivorous?

Tags: biology, humans, anatomy

It's often hotly debated online that humans are not true omnivores, but rather herbivores that have conditioned themselves to be able to handle certain degrees of cooked meat.

Honestly, I don't care about whether or not this is true, and am not interested in debating this subject. What I AM interested in is this:

What can genetic engineering do to make a human GI tract more omnivorous? From what we currently know now to what we may be able to achieve in the distant future, what edits can be made to the genetics of a human GI tract to make them capable of eating larger varieties of both meat AND herbs? Is such a balance and range in diet biologically possible to implement into a genetically-engineered human? If so, how much can we change the genes like this without making reproduction/crossbreeding with regular humans genetically impossible? How much of the current setup for the genes of a human gastrointestinal system can be kept?

My overall goal is finding a balance between genetically engineered human that's at impressively more capable of eating various meats and herbs than regular humans, using the power of genetic engineering to splice their genes before or after being born, yet at the same time, also still be capable of reproducing/cross-breeding with regular humans?

Comment: An animal is either omnivorous or it isn't. You can't be 'more omnivorous'.

Comment: Like it already looks like. Humans are omnivores after all. I mean look at bears, they're omnivores [and there's nothing that special regarding their digestive track](https://www.google.com/search?q=bear+digestive+system&oq=bear+digestive+system+&aqs=chrome..69i57.4818j0j7&client=tablet-android-samsung-nf-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8). At most we'd have something like longer intestines (and better adaptations for hunting and eating raw meat, if you wanna go into ditching every single bit of technology we have developed to hunt and prepare food) .

Comment: ... or a change to the gut bacteria.

Comment: By fixing the number of organs you are ruling out the possibility of making humans more capable of digesting vegetables by using a double stomach like most of the herbivores do.

Comment: @MatthewWells I would argue that's more the limitation of the definition of the word. For example, if you are a carnivore that can eat one kind of vegetable but every other kind kills you, are you really an omnivore? By the conventional definition you would be, but c'mon. I think you would agree that goes against the intent of the word even though it meets the definition.

Comment: To make humans "more carnivorous", you'd have to shorten the GI tract, which would make us worse at handling anything *but* meat. To make us "more herbivorous", you'd have to make us more like ruminants, which violates your 'same number of organs' requirement. Humans range from vegan to nearly-strict-carnivore (e.g. Inuit). I don't know what else you want...

Comment: the only effective way to make us better able to handle a more diverse diet i can think of is to have two stomach chambers and more powerful acids, but theres no way to have a multichamber digestive system without adding organs. the minimum number that would be added is one, but if you have two more added (a stomach chamber and a fermentation chamber) then it would be an even greater improvement, at the cost of being less adept at handling raw or stiff meat. its anatomically impossible to be a perfectly ideal omnivore without literally having multiple digestive systems for different jobs.

Comment: Your edit has complicated matters beyond hope of a single best answer. Please edit further to ask a single clear question. (From review).

Answer (score 2):

Honestly if you want to be able to eat anything I see one major change you need to make. Good news is it’s simple, bad news is I’m unsure about possible repercussions.

Add more gut bacteria!

So you know termites right? The little bugs famous for eating wood? Turns out they can’t digest cellulose, also known as wood pulp. In other words they can’t digest the only thing they eat. *However,* they do have bacteria in their gut that can digest wood, and they pass the nutrients on to the termite itself.

The solution for you is to add various types of bacteria to the human digestive tract which can digest things like wood and poisonous substances while creating useful byproducts for said human *without* producing substances that are extremely toxic, or replicating themselves to the extent of harming the host. More good news here is that those problems could be easily handwaved away by saying that the bacteria and humans adapted a mutually symbiotic relationship so that both parties aid each other, just like current bacteria in the human gut.

Basically the answer here is just take something that already occurs in nature and turn it up a few notches!

Comment: That can actually cause a lot of problems. Ruminants and other specialized herbivorous ungulates have a lot of trouble eating protein-rich foods without a lot of gastrointestinal distress because the bacteria in their gut break down simple sugars and proteins faster than the animal can digest them, and produce gas as a byproduct. This can lead to health problems in domestic animals.

Comment: Yeah that would take a bit of hand waving. Maybe the answer is to make people part chicken. Chickens can eat anything. Honestly if they were a bit larger every other land animal would probably be extinct by now.

Comment: This might be able to work if we could genetically re-engineer gastro intestinal bacteria to do this. It would also increase the diversity of gastro intestinal bacteria.

Comment: the problem is that unless your frequently eating foods with the specific poisons theyre built for, the bacteria are going to die off from malnutrition, meaning they wont be passed on to the next generation. also, in some cases, the bacteria will produce a waste byproduct that is even worse, requiring either another bacteria to process it, or the same bacteria to also convert that poison to something useable, too, both of which are hard to sustain.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that rats have excellent livers so can eat even more things than humans due to superior detoxification. So give humans rat-like livers.

Also, whatever allows animals to to digest cellulose and lignin. This tends to require the help of microbes however and there's a reason grazers have multiple stomachs.